# Profile pictures in chat rooms have odd green squares on them

Tags: bug, chat, images, mobile-web

I'm on Android, and it seems that the chat room profile icons have a weird green hue to them. I'm unsure why, but it definitely seems like a bug.

> [image]

Comment: This *might* just be a bug with Android or the Chrome browser. This didn't start happening for me (or I didn't notice it) until my phone received the Lollipop update.

Comment: I've been experiencing this too on my Nexus 7 on 5.1.

Comment: Repro on chrome 41 on  android 4.4.2

Comment: Repro on Chrome 41, Nexus 5 on 5.1.